# What is a quotient structure?

Tags: lambda-calculus, proof-assistants

I was reading a paper [here](http://www.chargueraud.org/research/2009/ln/main.pdf), and it mentioned "quotient structure" in the following sentence (third page, second paragraph of the paper)

> In order to obtain a representation of terms truly isomorphic to
>   λ-terms, we need to build a quotient structure, quotient the set of
>   raw terms with respect to alpha-equivalence. This construction based
>   on a quotient corresponds very closely to the of presentation from
>   standard textbooks on λ-calculus.

I am hoping that someone could point me a good tutorial on quotient structures.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about quotients recently that you may find useful: http://www.hedonisticlearning.com/posts/quotient-types-for-programmers.html

Comment: In mathematics this is called a *congruence* (an equivalence relation which is compatible with the algebraic or other structure). The author is probably using the term "quotient structure" because he's a computer scientists. They see structures everywhere, and are not necessarily aware of traditional mathematical terminology.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The idea is that two expressions which are α-equivalent are not meaningfully different. λx.λy.x and λz.λy.z are technically different expressions. They are α-equivalent, though, they intuitively represent the same thing. In most circumstances, differentiating between them is useless at best, counter-productive at most.

The quotient set is a formal definition that allows to say “we consider α-equivalent expressions to actually be the same”. So what is this formal definition?

#### Equivalence relation

First of all, an **equivalence relation** ~ on a set *S* is a binary relation that is:

- reflexive: for every *x* in *S*, *x ~ x*.
- symmetric: for *x, y* in *S*, if *x ~ y*, then *y ~ x*.
- transitive: for *x, y, z* in *S*, if *x ~ y* and *y ~ z*, then *x ~ z*.

> Examples:
>
> - For any set, = is an equivalence relation.
> - *a = b* (mod *n*) is an equivalence relation.
> - α-equivalence is an equivalence relation.

#### Equivalence class and quotient set

Now, given *S* and ~, and *a* in *S*, the **equivalence class** of *a* for ~ is the set [*a*] of all *x* in *S* such that *x ~ a*.

By reflexivity, it is clear that each *x* in *S* is in [*x*].
Moreover, using symmetry and transitivity, you can show that if *x* in [*y*], then [*y*] = [*x*]. So each *x* is in a single equivalence class, two distinct equivalence classes do not intersect.

Given *S* and ~, the set {[*x*] | *x* in *S*} of every equivalent class is a partition of S. This partition is called **quotient set** of *S* by ~ (usually noted *S*/~).

> Example:
> For the relation = (mod 5) on ***Z***, the equivalence classes are [0], [1], [2], [3], [4]. Each integer is equal to a single 0 ≤ *n* ≤ 4 modulo 5.

Usually, one doesn’t bother writing the [ ] when it’s not necessary.

Comment: So basically, every equivalent class is a quotient set. I know equivalence relations but did not know quotient set. Your description made it clear to me. Thx :)

Comment: @alim No, every *element* of a quotient set is an equivalence class. A quotient set is a collection of equivalence classes (that all together partition the original set).

Answer (score 5):

It's a term coming from abstract algebra. When you quotient a set $S$ with respect to some [equivalence relation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_relation) $\sim$, you are replacing the set $S$ with its [equivalence classes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_class) under $\sim$. Often the set $S$ has operations defined on it, and in that case we want these operations to be well defined for the quotient $S/\sim$, in the sense that if $x_i \sim y_i$ then $x_1 \circ x_2 \sim y_1 \circ y_2$. This allows us to define $\circ$ on the quotient.

An example in real analysis is $L^p$ spaces, in which functions are defined "up to measure zero".

Comment: If someone doesn’t know what a quotient set is, I wouldn’t expect them to be familiar with equivalence classes. I would add a definition of the term to make the answer more accessible.